# Localization and initial objects

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be a ring and let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$.

Why is the map from $A$ to $S^{-1}A$ initial among all $A$-algebras $B$?

Why does localization not have to commute with respect to infinite products?

Comment: What does initial mean for a map?  Do you mean that it makes $S^{-1}A$ an initial object in the category of $A$-algebras?  That must not be what you mean because $A$ itself is the initial object in that category and $A$ is not usually isomorphic to $S^{-1}A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The map from $A$ to $S^{-1}A$ is not initial among all $A$-algebras $B$. It is initial among all $A$-algebras $B$ such that $S$ maps into $B^\times$ under the structural map $A\rightarrow B$. This is the universal property of $S^{-1}A$, and is usually stated either as the definition of $S^{-1}A$ (which is then constructed explicitly via fractions) or proved immediately after construction $S^{-1}A$.

Localization (of $A$-modules or $A$-algebras) fails to commute with infinite products in general because localizing a module $M$ is the same as tensoring over $A$ with $S^{-1}A$, and tensor product generally doesn't commute with infinite products. I'm not sure what else you're looking for with this second question, but maybe somebody else can provide better insight.

For an example with $A=\mathbf{Z}$ and $S=\mathbf{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, so $S^{-1}A=\mathbf{Q}$, if you take the product $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}=\prod_p\mathbf{Z}_p$ where $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers, there is a natural map from $\mathbf{Q}\otimes_\mathbf{Z}\hat{\mathbf{Z}}\rightarrow\prod_p(\mathbf{Q}\otimes_\mathbf{Z}\mathbf{Z}_p)=\prod_p\mathbf{Q}_p$ and it is injective, but far from being surjective. The tuples you get in $\prod_p\mathbf{Q}_p$ from $\mathbf{Q}\otimes_\mathbf{Z}\hat{\mathbf{Z}}$ are precisely the ones of the form $(x_p)_p$ with $x_p$ integral (i.e. an element of $\mathbf{Z}_p$) for all but finitely many primes $p$. This is because every element of the source has the form $(1/m)\otimes(z_p)_p$ where $z_p\in\mathbf{Z}_p$ for all $p$, so you're only introducing denominators at the primes dividing $m$. An explicit element in the target which is not in the image would be $(1/p)_p$.

The source (or rather its image in $\prod_p\mathbf{Q}_p$) is called the ring of finite adeles of $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: How do you show the universal property?

Comment: Dear @Arul, The would need to know your definition of $S^{-1}A$ in order to answer that, but assuming $S^{-1}A$ is the set of equivalence classes of pairs $(a,s)\in A\times S$ with $(a,s)$ equivalent to $(b,t)$ whenever there is $u\in S$ with $uta=usb$, then you just prove it explicitly. Given a ring map $f:A\rightarrow B$ sending $S$ into $B^\times$, there is only one choice for where to send $a/s$, namely $f(a)f(s)^{-1}$. Then you verify this is well-defined, a homomorphism, and the unique such homomorphism compatible in the obvious sense with the map $a\mapsto a/s:A\rightarrow S^{-1}A$.

Comment: Thats what I meant. Thankyou.

Comment: your answer for second question is interesting. Where can I find more info about this?

Comment: Dear @Arul, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want more information about the $p$-adic numbers? That can be found in most texts on algebraic number theory: Neukirch, Janusz, Cassels-Frolich, Lang, etc..